# How to send base64 code to my webservice in react-native?

Tags: react-native

*I try to send my Image from react-native to my database.* 
*it sends my image's base64 code. However, base64 code is too long so my webservice doesnt take all of them. How can I send it ?*

**This is what I tried :**

```
selectPhoto = () => {
    const options = {};
    ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, response => {
      if (response.uri) {
        this.setState({ data: response.data });
      }
    });
  }

 sendImage() {
    fetch('url',  {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: new Headers({
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json', // <-- Specifying the Content-Type
      }),
      body: JSON.stringify(this.state.data), // data has base64 code
    })
  }
```

Comment: I used this **'react-native-image-base64'** to convert my image to base64 string.

Comment: I can take base64 string. problem is that, base64 string is too long  because of size of image.

Comment: ok then try it to send in array.Make changes in your web-service.